# A table of MySQL database asociated to Django App is "corrupted"

Tags: mysql, django

I have a problem that has never happened to me before. It is an application made with Django that has never given me errors. For some reason, a table in the database (MySQL) is now corrupted, but the app is still working.

However, when I make a call like this: `queryset = Tuition.objects.filter(agent = user)` Then, the database gives me this error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1712, 'Index base_tuition_agent_id_b1b4dfb6_fk_base_staff_user_ptr_id is corrupted')`

But, if I change the call to: `queryset = Tuition.objects.filter(Q(date__lte="1900-01-01")|Q(agent=user))` Then, There is no error... Surprise! (Obviously in the database there is no date prior to 1900 so both functions are similar).

But, if I change the call to: `queryset = Tuition.objects.filter(Q(date__gte="1900-01-01")&Q(agent=user))` Then, the database through the error again...

So:

- If I filter by "agent" doesn't work.
- If I filter with an "OR" conditional combining the "agent" field with another one it works.
- If I filter with an "AND" conditional combining the "agent" field with another one doesn't work.

You can see the details of the table here:
[image: MYSQL TABLE DETAILS]

I don't know much about MySQL and would like to know how the result of the above calls is possible. Because from my ignorance, the normal thing would be that none of them work, or well, that they all work.

To fix it, I have tried to duplicate the table with no success. I have tried exporting and importing it without success. And I have tried to change the parameter innodb_force_recovery=3 of mysql but I am not very clear how it works.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you look at ["Best Ways to Repair InnoDB Table Corruption in MySQL"](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/repair-innodb-table-corruption-in-mysql/) or equivalent web pages?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I try the command `DROP TABLE base_tuition;` it returns `ERROR 3730 (HY000): Cannot drop table 'base_tuition' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'base_tuition_curso_tuition_id_e9656ead_fk_base_tuition_id' on table 'base_tuition_curso'`

Comment: Found discussions that suggest running `OPTIMIZE TABLE base_tuition` may rebuild the table and it's indexes